# Copying files to folder

Tags: java, file, jsp, file-upload

I have this:

In addMusic.jsp:

```
<form method="post" action="Handler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Musica:</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add_musica_nome" placeholder="Nome Musica">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Localização:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="add_musica_path" accept="audio/*">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Ano:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add_musica_ano" pattern="[0-9]{4,4}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="logica" id="logica" value="SMusica"/>
        <input  type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="addMusica"/> 
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Inserir" name="inserir"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Handler:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String parametro = request.getParameter("logica"); // Recebe como parametro do jsp, qual a class do service que
                                                        // irá atuar
    String nomeDaClasse = "services." + parametro; // Nome da Classe

    try {
        Class<?> classe = Class.forName(nomeDaClasse);
        Logica logica = (Logica) classe.newInstance();

        String pagina = logica.executa(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("A lógica causou uma exceção", e);
    }
}
```

and in SMusica:

```
final String Dest = "/data/";

public void addMusica(String musica_nome, Part musica, String ano) throws IOException {

    String fileName = Paths.get(musica.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.

    try {

        File music = new File(fileName);

        System.out.println("Path: " + music.getAbsolutePath());

        if (music.renameTo(new File(Dest + music.getName()))) {
            System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public String executa(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

    if (req.getParameter("acao").equals("addMusica")) {
        addMusica(req.getParameter("add_musica_nome"), req.getPart("add_musica_path"),
                req.getParameter("add_musica_ano"));
    }
    return "/index.jsp";
}
```

And i made a print of absolutePath of music(File) and it returns C:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\eclipse\ProfJam_-_Mortalhas.mp3, not the real path.

My question is how can i get the real path of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in path called

```
  Path _rp = p.toRealPath();
```

Maybe you Can search in this direction

Comment: I searched this method, that i didnt knew, I came up with this to test:      
                                                                                                                                Path p = Paths.get(music.getPath(), music.getName()); 
   
System.out.println("Path: " + p);                                         
                                                                                                                       In the same method inside try catch and it printed:  UsersFabioDesktopProfJam_-_Mortalhas.mp3\UsersFabioDesktopProfJam_-_Mortalhas.mp3

Comment: But what is the path if your file, thé absolute math is not correct?

Comment: If you want to copy thé filé, you should use the class Files like this: Files.copy(source,dest)